# apache to nginx?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, nginx

I need to be able to use .htaccess, PHP 5, MySQL 5 on new configuration.

While I was looking for a way to increase server performance, someone suggests me to change my current system, Apache + Plesk, to Nginx with PHP-FPM, APC setup. I wonder if I can use this system considering my needs above ?

I don't have much information about managing server etc. So please let me know if I need to add something else here.

Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2):

nginx doesn't support .htaccess; all configuration needs to happen at the main server level

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use NGINX to serve PHP sites backed by MySQL.  It's not quite as simple as Apache's support for PHP, but it's not terribly hard, and is well-documented on the web.

Look into PHP-FPM

Check out http://interfacelab.com/nginx-php-fpm-apc-awesome/ and http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian to start

When all else fails, there is always the documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration

Comment: Thank you for the generous answer. I think I cannot use the new system with Plesk, can I?

Comment: I can't say; I have no experience with Plesk.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx can run circles around apache in a fraction of the resources if configured correctly. Plesk usually has nginx installed, but from the ones I have seen, it' used as a proxy.

You have to install php-fpm to use nginx+php and it is quite a bit more involved than setting up apache with mod-php. If you don't have access to the shell, where you can compile from source, stick with apache.